# How can I assign an element to variable?

Tags: jquery, variables, reference

For example:
I want to create shortcut to element array

```
var $artifacts = $('.game-artifact');
```

but atm there aren't any elements with such class. Then comes some code, which adds elements. The question is if, after I add these elements will variable $artifacts still refer to them or it will remain null? If so, how I manage to assign a reference to function to a variable?

Comment: FWIW, `$artifacts` will not be `null` in the first place. Empty jQuery objects are still objects, not `null`.

Comment: what you are looking for is object binding. Like said here often enough, $artifacts will remain empty until you reasign it with new values. Here is demo of that behaviour: http://jsfiddle.net/F7juA/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It will remain empty. You can update the reference once you have already added the elements:

```
// add elements
artifacts = $('.game-artifact');
```

Take a look at [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZqyqJ/2/).

Comment: So do I have to manually update each reference or is there any magic way to do so?
Like reference in c++ ( a &= b )

Comment: I don't see how you could do it "beforehand". Since you can add elements dynamically at any point (f.e. by asynchronous ajax calls) you'll never know what to point at, at the time of variable declaration.

Answer (score 6):

You can wrap it with function which will return current elements:

```
var artifacts = function(){
  return $('.game-artifact');
};

var $artifacts = artifacts();
```

Comment: Do you really define a function for each query?

Comment: @undefined No, I do not.

Comment: IMHO this is an anti-pattern. If `artifacts` was a public method of an object then it would make more sense.

Answer (score 1):

You should use .get() over accessing the array directly, to avoid out of bound errors.

```js
var lists = $("body li");
console.log(lists.length);  // returns 20
console.log(lists.get(25)); // returns undefined.
console.log(lists[25]);     // Generates an error.
```